# Why the rA:rB is 2:8 instead of 2:f in the execution of a pushl instruction?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, instructions, y86

I'm reading the 4th chapter of Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective and learn about the sequential Y86 implementations.So here is the Assembly code:
[image]

And we trace the execution of the pushl instruction to analysis each step of the push operation.Here is the process,left part is generic,right part is specific:
[image]

I can understand all of the steps except for the rA:rB.Look at the first picture and the instruction is a02f,so in this condition,icode:ifun should be a:0,rA:rB should be 2:f.However,accodring to the book,rA:rB is actually 2:8 instead of 2:f.But why?And I really don't know where the '8' come from.

Comment: The assembly listing shows `pushl` is `A02F`, yet the aside says that the `pushl` is `A028`,   Some texts indicate `F` is used to encode no-register, while others use 8 there.  I take it that either encoding is allowed.  You can see that for `pushl` in generic or specific, `rB` is not used, so apparently doesn't matter too much.

Comment: "the aside says that the pushl is A028",where?

Comment: "We can also see that the instruction is located at address 0x01a and consists of 2 bytes having values 0xa0 and 0x28."

Comment: But I don't know where could he conclude this.He just directly said that conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s an errata, and it’s listed in the [errata page for the 2nd edition of the book](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/errata.html):

**Chapter 4: Processor Architecture**

- *p. 370, Aside tracing the pushl instruction:* The second instruction byte should be 0x2f, instead of 0x28. The value of rB in the Fetch stage should be 0xf instead of 0x8.